# Laravel / Eloquent order by showing wrong order

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im trying to select users from the users tables via Eloquent in Laravel 6 and ordering them by the first_name column.  Some of the users first name's have 2 words e.g

```
id        first_name        last_name
1         Alf               Walker
2         Brian             Smith
3         David             Jones
4         Adrian Matthew    Brown
5         Terry             Edwards
6         Carl Luke         Boothe
```

Now I have my eloquent query like the following:

```
$users = User::where("is_active", 1)->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')->get();
```

However it returns them in order

```
Alf
Brian
David
Terry
Adrian Matthew
Carl Luke
```

It looks like if first_name has a space in it then its sorting it after its sorted anything that doesnt have a space. Im expecting it to for example to list `Adrian Matthew` before `Alf` because its alphabetically first.

I output the Eloquent query to SQL which shows:

```
select * from `users` where `is_active` = ? order by `first_name` asc
```

I ran this query direct in the database (filling in is_active) and it returned in the expected order. So the query is right but Eloquent is not returning it in the right order.

Has anyone seen this before?  Ive tried to google the isue and look it up here on stackoverflow but I can't find out a fix.

here is the output to

> dd($users->pluck('first_name')->toArray());

```
array:44 [▼
  0 => " Alina"
  1 => " Andrade"
  2 => " Andrew"
  3 => " Ashley"
  4 => " Bianca"
  5 => " Daniel"
  6 => " Elena"
  7 => " Enriko"
  8 => " Francis"
  9 => " Geanina"
  10 => " George"
  11 => " Georgi"
  12 => " Georgian"
  13 => " Gheorghe"
  14 => " Hayley"
  15 => " Ingus"
  16 => " Ioan"
  17 => " Ion"
  18 => " Ivars"
  19 => " Jack"
  20 => " Karl"
  21 => " Kay"
  22 => " Kosta"
  23 => " Lauris"
  24 => " Micheal"
  25 => " Mirela"
  26 => " Nicole"
  27 => " Rima"
  28 => " Ryan"
  29 => " Samuel"
  30 => " Silvestru"
  31 => " Skaiste"
  32 => " Steven"
  33 => " Terry"
  34 => " Viorica"
  35 => "Aleksandrs Viljams"
  36 => "Andrei Iulian"
  37 => "Andrei Lucretiu"
  38 => "Diana Monica"
  39 => "Elena Diana"
  40 => "Nicoleta Ionela"
  41 => "Tibi Daniel"
  42 => "Vasile Danut"
  43 => "Victor Vlad"
]
```

Comment: Right after `$users`, add `dd($users->pluck('first_name')->toArray());` and add that output to the question. It looks like it's still sorting by `id`, but I don't see why that would be the case unless you weren't using `$users` (i.e. you defined `$users` but then used `User::...` somewhere else instead)

Comment: what is the output of `dd(User::where("is_active", 1)->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')->toSql());`?

Comment: @HafezDivandari They already added that: *"I output the Eloquent query to SQL which shows: `select * from users where is_active = ? order by first_name asc`"*....

Comment: sorry my bad, I thought that was a manually written sql.

Comment: Ived added the dd output to the question which has the actual names from the table by names in the quesiton above were just examples.

Comment: @azzy81 There's your issue; half of those names have a leading space ` A` vs `A`; the code is functioning as expected, but you've got some bad data it seems.

Comment: arh yep I see it  damn that space ^^  Thank you Tim Lewis